# Using JSON data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-mobile

I have not done this before, so need some leads. I have a ASP.NET MVC4 (beta) project - Mobile project - setup. And I am given a set of REST APIs to consume. How would I do this? The APIs return data in JSON format. Do you have any examples, best practices...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `$.ajax` method to send an AJAX request to the Web Api controller on the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/values/123',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        // if the controller returned JSON data, the data argument
        // will represent a javascript object that you could directly
        // access its properties 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. So how do I consume the data in ASP.NET MVC? The examples show that I don't need "ASP.NET MVC"-ish code to use the data... all that we need is jQuery. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you want to consume the service from the client side you use javascript. If you want to consume it from a web application you could use the HttpClient which is the client framework of the Web API: http://www.johnnycode.com/blog/2012/02/23/consuming-your-own-asp-net-web-api-rest-service/

Comment: Thanks Darin. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DownloadString` method of `WebClient` class. That will give you a string output of what the RESTURL is returning. You can convert that to Json and iterate the results

```
string address="http://yourrestdomain/customer/234";
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```